# Css list problem

Tags: css, list

How can I fix my css list problem form text displaying like this inside a div tag.

```
# ordered lists - the 
list items are marked with numbers or letters
```

To display like this when inside a div tag.

```
# ordered lists - the 
  list items are marked with numbers or letters.
```

here is the html.

```
        <div>
            <h2>header</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>ordered lists - the list items are marked with numbers or letters</li>
                    <li>ordered lists - the list items are marked with numbers or letters</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS.

```
div {
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background: #fff;
    float: right;
    width: 302px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}

div h2 {
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    width: 302px;
    color: #fFF;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}

div ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 308px;
}

div li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 282px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two?

Comment: can we see your html snippet and css for it?

Comment: @Pekka, the second line of the second example is indented - I had trouble spotting it.

Comment: the way the text is displayed is the problem

Comment: @Matt ah, I see, true. @css can you show some code? Isn't that the standard behaviour within list items already?

Answer (score 0):

```
div > ul { 
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is `list-style-position: inside`, the other one is `list-style-position: outisde` and some padding.

Comment: possibly there is a more specific css rule that changes this property to 'inside' -- look with firebug, it lets you see what css rules apply to a specific element

Answer (score 0):

combine Unorder and order list like as below will do the thing you want

[image]

```
 <UL>
      <LH>Table Fruit</LH>
      <LI>apples
      <LI>oranges
      <LI>bananas
      <ol>
             <li>Coffee</li>
             <li>Milk</li>
         </ol>
</UL>
```

Comment: I think the `ol` should be nested in a `li`

Comment: Also, has the `<lh>` tag actually ever existed, except from early HTML 3.0 drafts?